# SQLDeveloper.exe itself is getting access denied

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-sql-developer

Installed Oracle 11g and the 11g client.  Everytime I start SQLDeveloper it prompts for the java.exe and again which files to associate.  It must be trying to save this in registry (or maybe disk).  I'm going to try "run as Admin" - is that required?

I see this "access is denied" in the command window.  I'm starting it by running this .exe:

Part 2 of my quesiton/issue - I'm on Win 7, from the start menu, I search for "SQL Dev...", and the entry that shows up is a link to the following .BAT file that doesn't even exist: 
- C:\Oracle11gClientApp\neal.walters\product\11.2.0\client_1\SQLDEVELOPER\SQLDEVELOPER\BIN\SQLDEVELOPER.BAT 
The directory exists, but no .BAT files in it.  The closest physical .bat file I can see is this one: c:\Oracle11gClientApp\neal.walters\product\11.2.0\client_1\sqldeveloper\sqlcli.bat  (and it gives an "index out of range" when I run it.

> oracle.ide.natives.registry.RegistryException: Access is denied.
>
> ```
>     at oracle.ide.natives.registry.RegistryKey.createKey(Native Method)
>     at oracle.ide.config.FileAssociations.addAssociation(FileAssociations.
> ```
>
> va:617)
>           at oracle.ide.config.FileAssociations.setAssociated(FileAssociations.j
>   a:244)
>           at oracle.ide.config.FileAssociations.setAssociations(FileAssociations
>   ava:264)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ConfigureFileAssociationsDialog.saveData(Confi
>   reFileAssociationsDialog.java:101)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ConfigureFileAssociationsDialog.(Configu
>   FileAssociationsDialog.java:69)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ShellIntegration.showConfigurationDialog(Shell
>   tegration.java:152)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ShellIntegration.mav$showConfigurationDialog(S
>   llIntegration.java:48)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ShellIntegration$2.mainWindowOpened(ShellInteg
>   tion.java:129)
>           at oracle.ide.IdeCore.fireIdeEvent(IdeCore.java:855)
>           at oracle.ide.IdeCore.mav$fireIdeEvent(IdeCore.java:124)
>           at oracle.ide.IdeCore$3.run(IdeCore.java:815)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Protection
>   main.java:75)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchTh
>   ad.java:201)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThrea
>   java:116)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchTh
>   ad.java:105)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:10
>
> ```
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```
>
> oracle.ide.natives.registry.RegistryException: Access is denied.
>
> ```
>     at oracle.ide.natives.registry.RegistryKey.createKey(Native Method)
>     at oracle.ide.config.FileAssociations.addAssociation(FileAssociations.
> ```
>
> va:617)
>           at oracle.ide.config.FileAssociations.setAssociated(FileAssociations.j
>   a:244)
>           at oracle.ide.config.FileAssociations.setAssociations(FileAssociations
>   ava:264)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ConfigureFileAssociationsDialog.saveData(Confi
>   reFileAssociationsDialog.java:101)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ConfigureFileAssociationsDialog.(Configu
>   FileAssociationsDialog.java:69)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ShellIntegration.showConfigurationDialog(Shell
>   tegration.java:152)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ShellIntegration.mav$showConfigurationDialog(S
>   llIntegration.java:48)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ShellIntegration$2.mainWindowOpened(ShellInteg
>   tion.java:129)
>           at oracle.ide.IdeCore.fireIdeEvent(IdeCore.java:855)
>           at oracle.ide.IdeCore.mav$fireIdeEvent(IdeCore.java:124)
>           at oracle.ide.IdeCore$3.run(IdeCore.java:815)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Protection
>   main.java:75)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchTh
>   ad.java:201)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThrea
>   java:116)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchTh
>   ad.java:105)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:10
>
> ```
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```
>
> oracle.ide.natives.registry.RegistryException: Access is denied.
>
> ```
>     at oracle.ide.natives.registry.RegistryKey.createKey(Native Method)
>     at oracle.ide.config.FileAssociations.addAssociation(FileAssociations.
> ```
>
> va:617)
>           at oracle.ide.config.FileAssociations.setAssociated(FileAssociations.j
>   a:244)
>           at oracle.ide.config.FileAssociations.setAssociations(FileAssociations
>   ava:264)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ConfigureFileAssociationsDialog.saveData(Confi
>   reFileAssociationsDialog.java:101)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ConfigureFileAssociationsDialog.(Configu
>   FileAssociationsDialog.java:69)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ShellIntegration.showConfigurationDialog(Shell
>   tegration.java:152)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ShellIntegration.mav$showConfigurationDialog(S
>   llIntegration.java:48)
>           at oracle.ideimpl.shell.ShellIntegration$2.mainWindowOpened(ShellInteg
>   tion.java:129)
>           at oracle.ide.IdeCore.fireIdeEvent(IdeCore.java:855)
>           at oracle.ide.IdeCore.mav$fireIdeEvent(IdeCore.java:124)
>           at oracle.ide.IdeCore$3.run(IdeCore.java:815)
>           at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Protection
>   main.java:75)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchTh
>   ad.java:201)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThrea
>   java:116)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchTh
>   ad.java:105)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:10
>
> ```
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of SQL developer behaved oddly and these oddities may be relevant:

- if the program was saved in a file path with a space, Eg: "My Documents" it did not work
- if you tried to use an existing java install it might or might not throw an error that the java version was too old

Try moving the program to a file path where you have rights to save.  I have not needed to run it with admin privileges.

I can run the current version, 4, from a networked drive, if I use the sqldeveloperw.exe shortcut which you can find by poking around in the program folder, (possibly the bin)?

Comment: I'm 99% sure it needed admin to store the path to the java.exe in the registry (because I did it and it worked, and because of the error, which was not file system related). So what's up with the .bat files?  Do you run the .exe, do you run the .bat files, does the client install properly put an icon in Windows Start Menu?